# Problems connecting to the Samba server over the Internet

Tags: samba, smb

My problem: When my friend tries to connect to the network drive he gets an error message.

> "Make sure the name is spelled correctly. There may be a network
> error."

But he entered everything correctly "\\Public-IP\folder". However, I can access the server without problems, e.g. via my smartphone (LTE). The port is enabled. Does anyone have an idea?
I use Samba on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: And what do the logs say? Do you see his traffic hitting the server?

Comment: Please add more details about the software used in all cases.

Comment: @Bib I don't see any traffic from him.

Comment: Then... 1. Your firewall is blocking the traffic, 2. Your ISP is blocking that traffic coming in, 3. Your friends ISP is blocking that traffic from going out onto the internet or 4. Your friends ISP is running some form of CGNAT which just cannot handle this kind of traffic. It is not unusual to block this kind of traffic due to how much havoc it has caused in the past. I suggest you set up a vpn for the person to connect into.